# java.lang.IllegalStateException Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android

I have read a lot of similar questions, but still couldn't find the answer.

I have an app deployed to the market, and I receive some IllegalStateException crash reports through BugSnag. But I can't reproduce it on my end, all the information I have for this problem is from BugSnag.

The stack trace for my problem is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateExceptionSplashScreenActivity
Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

java.lang.IllegalStateException · Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
FragmentManager.java:2044android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss  
FragmentManager.java:2067android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction   
BackStackRecord.java:680android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal   
BackStackRecord.java:634android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit   
FragmentTabHost.java:288android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow   
View.java:20011android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow   
ViewGroup.java:3589android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow  
ViewGroup.java:3596android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow  
ViewGroup.java:3596android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow  
ViewGroup.java:3596android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow  
ViewGroup.java:3596android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow  
ViewGroup.java:3596android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow  
ViewGroup.java:3596android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow  
ViewRootImpl.java:2262android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals   
ViewRootImpl.java:1927android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal 
ViewRootImpl.java:8558android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run   
Choreographer.java:949android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run 
Choreographer.java:761android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks    
Choreographer.java:696android.view.Choreographer.doFrame    
Choreographer.java:935android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run  
Handler.java:873android.os.Handler.handleCallback   
Handler.java:99android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage   
Looper.java:214android.os.Looper.loop   
ActivityThread.java:7124android.app.ActivityThread.main 
Method.java:-2java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke   
RuntimeInit.java:494com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
ZygoteInit.java:975com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
```

The following is my program logic. The FragmentTabHost is only used in `HomeActivity`. Its setup is done entirely in `onCreate`, and it is not touched in other lifecycle callbacks.

[image: program logic]

From the bugsnag, I get the following breadcrumb. From the breadcrumb I can see the exception happens when the user press home_key or recent_app right after launch and in early phase of HomeActivity.

[image: Breadcrumb]
My questions are:

1. Why the Exception is registered under the SplashScreenActivity, shouldn't that activity finish long before the HomeActivity?
2. I see that TabHost tries to commit fragment transaction after `onSaveInstanceState()`, but any methods that involve committing fragments are executed in `onCreate`, why those commit events are scheduled after `onPause`?

Comment: Hi Harry. Does "Developer Options" -> "Don't Keep Activities" -> ON, help reproduce it?

Comment: @Elletlar thanks, just wonder why "Don't keep activities" would help reproduce my problem?

Comment: Possibly. It will cause the Activities to be recreated constantly. I noticed the error happened during onSaveInstanceState which means the framework was planning to recreate the Activity. For each Activity, with that setting turned ON, you might try tasking away to the homescreen and coming back to force Activity recreation. Cheers.